# Does Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer respect JsonIgnore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I am getting an error during deserialization using ASPNET Core on AWS Lambda with C#.  I have the below attribute in my lambda assembly:

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
```

I have the [JsonIgnore] attribute on certain properties of the objects (classes) being passed in.  If these properties are called in their state, they will throw an Exception.

The Exception is being thrown when passing the object to the ASPNET Core controller (or when returning the value from a controller).

My theory is that the [JsonIgnore] attribute is not being respected.  I cannot find any documentation or other SO threads speaking to this.

Can you confirm/deny my theory?  Is there any documentation on this?  Can anyone think of a workaround?

Comment: It looks like they are using using Newtonsoft.Json; https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json/JsonSerializer.cs so it should support [JsonIgnore]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought but it is not complying with [JsonIgnore]

Answer (score 0):

The source for [Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json/JsonSerializer.cs) indicates it is a "Custom ILambdaSerializer implementation which uses Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1" which supports the [JsonIgnoreAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) (`[JsonIgnore]`).

[Announcing AWS Lambda support for .NET Core 3.1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-aws-lambda-supports-for-net-core-3-1/) introduces (and recommends) a new Lambda JSON serializer of [Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson/DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer.cs) using the [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) is built into the .NET Core framework, which also supports a [JsonIgnoreAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.1) (`[JsonIgnore]`).